# what compiler does visual studio 2012 use for C++ and is it compatible/can I use it with codeblocks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

What compiler does visual studio 2012 use for C++  and is it compatible/can I use it with codeblocks?

I want to know because we're required to use Visual Studio 2012 for this school project and I would like to be able to trial some things with codeblocks.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2012 is using the Microsoft compiler cl.exe. But anyway, you can maintain two projects (one for Visual Studio and one for CodeBlocks) - sharing the same source code.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can find the following on a windows based OS:

C compiler
Linker for dynamic libs
Linker for static libs:
Debugger:
Resource Compiler:
Make program:

I believe this would help me set up the compiler's with Codeblocks